# using std::remove_if to iterate and remove entries in deque

Tags: c++, lambda, iteration, deque

I am using std::remove_if to iterate through a deque to remove items found in a separate list. The logic seems straight forward but my test code seems to leave items remaining in the deque that should have been removed. I'm failing to see where the fault is in my logic.

```
int main()
{
    const int32_t STATUS_OK = 1;
    const int32_t STATUS_NOT_OK = 2;
    const int32_t STATUS_TEST = 3;

    std::deque<int32_t> error_codes;
    error_codes.push_front(STATUS_OK);
    error_codes.push_front(STATUS_NOT_OK);
    error_codes.push_front(STATUS_TEST);

    std::list<int32_t> ignored_codes;
    ignored_codes.push_back(STATUS_OK);
    ignored_codes.push_back(STATUS_NOT_OK);

    error_codes.erase(
        std::remove_if(
            begin(error_codes),
            end(error_codes),
            [ignored_codes](int32_t error_code) {
                for (auto ignore_code : ignored_codes)
                {
                    if (ignore_code == error_code)
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
                })
                // edit - this is what was missing:
                end(error_codes));        
    }
```

At the end of the execution, error_codes shows 2 items {3, 1} remaining in the deque. If I add an additional STATUS_NOT_OK into the error codes, then i am left with {3, 2, 1} in the error_codes deque, so... What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `erase(IT)` != `erase(Beg,End)` call the latter to remove range.

Comment: [Erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom). Note the arguments to `erase` call; compare and contrast with your example.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - thanks. Sorted out what i was missing due to that example.